# Image filename appears in Google SERP

Tags: google-search

I've just noticed that the filename of one of my images appears in Google SERP. The page in question is the first listing (Compass Cruises) in the attached screenshot. Can anyone suggest how I can fix this? Thanks.[image]

Comment: Interesting. I have not seen this happen before. Something new! Cheers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site you are referring to does not have a description meta tag. The description meta-tag is often where SERP snippets come from assuming that they are crafted well.

It appears that Google is taking the SERP snippet from two places, one is an image alt tag `alt="compass-cruises-612x340"` and the other is from the first paragraph tag. If the description meta-tag is missing, as it is in this case, or not crafted well, Google will attempt to create a snippet from information found on the page or from another source (rarely). One thing that can effect this are the search terms used.

***This should NOT happen. This is a Google error.***

However, this would not happen if the site had crafted a proper description meta-tag. This is a failure with both the site itself and Google.